# How to rbind multiple data frames individually in R?

Tags: r

There is a data frame (df) and a list of data frames(df1,df2..),
I want to rbind df with each df's in list and store in a new list.

50 data frames list

```
mylist # List of 50 elements
```

Another base data frame

```
single_data
```

I created an empty list

```
my_dfs = list()
```

I want to rbind single_data to every data frame in the list

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
  my_dfs[[i]] <- rbind(single_data, mylist$`i`) 
}
```

But rbind not happening, single_data has 5000 rows and mylist data frames has 5000 rows each, but my_dfs[[i]] having only 5000 rows.
If I do individually instead of loop it is working.

```
my_dfs1 <- rbind(single_data, mylist$`1`) 
my_dfs2 <- rbind(single_data, mylist$`2`) …
```

I except to work on loop.

Comment: I think `mapply(rbind, mylist, single_data)` should also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and `rbind` the 'single_data' with each of the `list` elements

```
mylistnew <- lapply(mylist, function(x) rbind(single_data, x))
```

---

If we use the `for` loop, use the `[[` instead of `$`.  Also, it is better to have `seq_along` instead of `1:length`

```
my_dfs <- vector('list', length(mylist))

for (i in seq_along(mylist)){
  my_dfs[[i]] <- rbind(single_data, mylist[[i]]) 
 }
```

Comment: Works Well, Thanks you